# Approximation for high SNR

Tags: signal-processing, digital-communications, snr

In Slide 6 of this [PDF](http://ece.tamu.edu/~georghiades/courses/ftp661/fading.pdf), it says that the performance of binary signaling is as follows:

[image]

I can understand the approximation for high SNR in the incoherent FSK and DPSK case, but how do we get the approximation for the coherent BPSK and FSK case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `coherent BPSK`, Taylor series expansion for is as follow,

If X = **SNR**, then its expansion for `[X/(1+X)]^1/2` is,
`=  1 - 1/2X + O(1/X^2)`, now put into your equation of `P(e)`,
You will get as you stated.

Note:

> > for all approximation you have to expand SNR equation through this formula,
> >      (aX + b)^n = a^n.X^n - n.a^(n-1).b.X^(n-1) ... n.a.b^(n-1).X + b^n

Using "a" "b" and "n" to stand for any coefficient or exponent we might have

Comment: Is there something missing after your first line? The Taylor series expansion?

Comment: No, is start from so, I think I have to remove, let me edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still can't tell how you got `[X/(1+X)]^1/2 =  1 - 1/2X + O(1/X^2)`...

Comment: It's ok now, I finally understand. Thanks for pointing me in the correct directions!

Comment: you're welcome...